# Can’t run a function against EXEC

Tags: sql-server, functions, syntax

My SQL Server book says you can't run a function inside `EXEC` and shows an example:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfLetters int = 15;
EXEC(‘SELECT LEFT(Name,’ + CAST(@NumberOfLetters AS varchar)
 + ‘) AS ShortName FROM Production.Product’);
```

This doesn't work as the `CAST()` function needs to be fully resolved prior to the `EXEC` line, so we can modify the code as:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfLetters AS int = 15;
DECLARE @str AS varchar(255);
SET @str = ‘SELECT LEFT(Name,’ + CAST(@NumberOfLetters AS varchar) + ‘) AS ShortName FROM Production.Product’;
EXEC(@str);
```

This time it works because, as mentioned above, the `CAST()` function needs to be fully resolved prior to the `EXEC` line.

But I have one more question, what about the `LEFT()` function, why it can be run against `EXEC`?

Answer (score 7):

The `LEFT()` function in your example is not part of the `EXEC` statement. It is inside the string representing part of the dynamic SQL to be executed by your `EXEC` statement.

In contrast, the `CAST()` function is used to *build* that string. If you use the correct quotation marks – `'` instead of `‘` & `’` – then perhaps you can also see the difference in the syntax highlighting:

```sql
DECLARE @NumberOfLetters int = 15;
EXEC('SELECT LEFT(Name,' + CAST(@NumberOfLetters AS varchar)
 + ') AS ShortName FROM Production.Product');
```

If syntax highlighting shows correctly on your monitor, then you should be able to see that the `LEFT` keyword is shown in red as part of a string, whereas the name `CAST` is shown in a different colour, and that is because it is not part of a string, rather it is part of an *expression* used to construct a string. That is precisely what the problem is: `EXEC (...)` does not accept an expression. It only accepts either a (single) string literal or a string variable.

Because you have to build your dynamic SQL script based on some values (the `@NumberOfLetters` value, in this case), you have to use a variable. You store the built script in it and then you pass it to the `EXEC` statement to run the dynamic script. That is what the modified code does:

```sql
DECLARE @NumberOfLetters AS int = 15;
DECLARE @str AS varchar(255);

-- you build the dynamic script first and store it in a variable
SET @str = 'SELECT LEFT(Name,' + CAST(@NumberOfLetters AS varchar)
         + ') AS ShortName FROM Production.Product';

-- then you just pass the variable to EXEC to run the dynamic script
EXEC(@str);
```

Comment: Also please read https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length and https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql